# How to resize button in my frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I have added two buttons to the south, but the button two is overlaying the first button. How can I somehow resize the button so that they are next to each other. Below is the code:

```
 Panel p = new Panel();

 p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 p.add(new Button("Throw Stick"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);//button 1 (B'1)
 p.add(new Button("Stick Draw"), BorderLayout.SOUTH); //This button is overlaying B'1.
 p.add(new Label("Player 1"), BorderLayout.EAST);
 p.add(new Label("Player 2"), BorderLayout.WEST);

 frame.add(p);
```

Comment: Change BorderLayout. Use flow layout for placing components next to each other.

Comment: you could add them to a panel with gridlayout and then add that panel on BorderLayout.SOUTH

Answer (score 3):

[`BorderLayout` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html):

> Each region may contain no more than one component.

In other words: You need to put both of your `Button`s into one `Component` (for example a `Panel`).